How to apply a condition over a large subset of columns from a table?
I want to apply a condition over several columns from a table. The columns are in the table (dictionary) called column_list. The main table, called user_STE, contains registers which need to be filtered, and those filters need to be applied over column_list (subset of the columns of user_STE, over 400). The condition is: For each register in user_STE at least 2 or more of the columns listed in column_list must be greater than 0 and not NULL. I am currently working with Databricks and I do not know how to do this. As I told you I need the table user_STE, but just the register where at least two or more columns from column_list are greater than 0 and not NULL. Any hint?
Here are the two datasets and what I tried.
WITH column_list AS (
    SELECT
        column_name
    FROM
        information_schema.columns
    WHERE
        table_name = 'ccdc_sustained_member_subs_engagement_pivot'
        AND table_schema = 'ccea_prod'
        AND column_name NOT LIKE '%ACROBAT%'
        AND column_name LIKE '%active_days%'
),
user_STE AS (
    SELECT
        *
    FROM
        ccea_prod.CCDC_sustained_member_subs_engagement_pivot
    WHERE
        market_area = 'US'
        AND period_end_Date = '2024-09-06'
        AND market_segment = 'EDUCATION'
        AND subscription_offerings = 'STE - All Apps'
        AND subscription_type = 'IN'
)

SELECT * FROM user_STE;

WITH column_list AS (
    SELECT column_name
    FROM information_schema.columns
    WHERE table_name = 'ccdc_sustained_member_subs_engagement_pivot'
    AND table_schema = 'ccea_prod'
    AND column_name NOT LIKE 'ACROBAT%'
    AND column_name LIKE '%active_days%'
),
user_STE AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM ccea_prod.ccdc_sustained_member_subs_engagement_pivot
    WHERE market_area = 'US'
    AND period_end_date = '2024-09-06'
    AND market_segment = 'EDUCATION'
    AND subscription_offerings = 'STE - All Apps'
    AND subscription_type = 'IN'
)
SELECT *
FROM user_STE
WHERE (
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM column_list
    WHERE COALESCE(NULLIF(user_STE.[column_name], 0), NULL) IS NOT NULL
) >= 2


You will have to generate a query, using the column selection criteria, that un-pivots exactly those columns you're looking for, generate  a CASE WHEN <colname> > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END on each of those columns, then group by the identifier(s) of ccdc_sustained_member_subs_engagement_pivot, HAVING the sum of those case-when expressions greater or equal to 2. Can you supply us with one example that does not satisfy the condition and two that do satisfy it, with a subset of the columns, as sample data? If you don't know how, ask for help

The table name ccdc_sustained_member_subs_engagement_pivot suggests it is a pivot, so presumably there is one or more tables that provided that data for that that pivot. You probably need those tables. Otherwise you will have to unpivot the table so the data you need is in multiple rows instead of multiple columns.

You can use below set of queries to achieve your goal, but create a table  or view column_list, user_STE.
DECLARE listColumns ARRAY<STRING>;
SET VAR listColumns = (SELECT array_agg(column_name) from column_list);

DECLARE queryStr STRING;
SET VAR queryStr = 'SELECT * FROM user_STE WHERE (' || aggregate(listColumns, '', (list, col) -> list || '(CASE WHEN `user_STE`.`' || col || '` > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)' || ' + ', list -> list || '0' ) || ' ) >= 2';

select queryStr; 

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE queryStr;

Here, first i am converting the column_list into array of strings then used aggregate function on that array to create a case condition on the column list to build query string .
Then executing the queryStr.
I have created sample table based on you data.



active_days_jan
active_days_feb
active_days_mar
active_days_apr




5
3
0
null


0
null
1
1


null
2
0
null


7
null
3
5


0
0
0
0



And below is the sample output:



active_days_jan
active_days_feb
active_days_mar
active_days_apr




5
3
0
null


0
null
1
1


7
null
3
5



